# Determining the number of parameters accepted by a method

Tags: c#, string, methods, parameters

Is it possible to get the number of parameters accepted by a method and then access the values of these parameters individually?  I want to create a method which concatenates the values of all the parameters of a method, except the last parameter.  However, the number of parameters and the name of the parameters depend on the method being accessed.

Is it possible to do something similar to the following pseudo-code?

```
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < Method.Parameters.Count - 1; i++)
{
     string.Append(Method.Parameters[i].Value);
}
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Pass an array to a method...

Comment: I want to ask why you want to do this, because there might be a better solution.

Comment: Basically, I want to verify the digital signature passed with a number of methods.  The digital signature is verified by first concatenating all the method's parameters, except the last parameter which is the digital signature itself, and then computing the signature based on the received data using the sender's public key.  However, I have to do this for a large number of methods which differ in the number and type of parameters accepted.

Comment: It sounds like you need to modify the methods in order to implement that. I'd be tempted to write for each method a sealed immutable class that encapsulates all the arguments and implements `GetHashCode()`. Then you'd pass an instance of that class instead, and you can simply use its hash code.

Comment: Have you considered generating the code for your methods, e.g., using T4 Templates?

Comment: To tell you the truth, no.  I will look into that possibility.  Thank you so much for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will do:

```
Type.GetType("MyClassType").GetMethod("foo").GetParameters().Length;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :)  One more question.  How do you access the parameters using an index?

Comment: The method I described works only as a descriptive method. It does not give you the concrete values of parameters while the method is executed. This only gives you meta data on the parameters. If you want to iterate over the parameters while executing the method you should use an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a method like

```
void Foo(string s, int x, int y, bool flag)
```

then you don't need to determine the number of arguments programmatically – you already know that there are 4 arguments.

```
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder().Append(s)
                                          .Append(x)
                                          .Append(y);
}
```

If you want the method accept any number of arguments, then you can use the [`params` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) to define your method as follows:

```
void Baz(params object[] args)
```

The arguments are passed as an array to your method, so you can determine the number of arguments from the array length:

```
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(args[i]);
    }
}
```

*Usage:*

```
Baz("xyzzy", 42, 0, false);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Unfortunately, I have around 20 methods to modify so I thought that if I did something which is generic I would save some time.